# If $s_1$ has spin up and $s_2$ has spin down how to find $s_1.s_2 $? what state should i take for coupled $s$ whether singlet or triplet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

Two spin half particle one up spin one down spin how to calculate $s_1\cdot s_2$? what state should I take triplet or singlet? while we don't encounter the problem in two spin up particle

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you know $s_1$ and $s_2$ and only want $s_1\cdot s_2,$ why do we need to rewrite the state in another basis? Maybe you could clarify why it's a problem for $\mid \uparrow\downarrow\rangle$ but not $\mid \uparrow\uparrow\rangle.$

Answer (score 0):

The total spin squared is:

$$ S^2 = (s_1 + s_2)^2 = s_1^2 + 2s_1\cdot s_2 + s_2^2$$

so:

$$ s_1\cdot s_2 = \frac 1 2 [S^2 - s_1^2-s_2^2]$$

Looking at an extremal triplet state:

$$ |1,1\rangle = |\frac 1 2, +\frac 1 2\rangle|\frac 1 2, +\frac 1 2\rangle \equiv |\psi\rangle$$

So:

$$\langle \psi|s_1\cdot s_2|\psi\rangle = \langle 1,1|  \frac 1 2 [S^2 - s_1^2-s_2^2]
|1,1\rangle
$$
$$ = \frac{\hbar^2}2[1(1+1)-\frac 1 2 (1+\frac 1 2)-\frac 1 2 (1+\frac 1 2)] =  \frac{\hbar^2}4$$

That is no more or less difficult than finding the expectation value for the operator in the state with one spin definitely up and one definitely down:

$$ |\frac 1 2, +\frac 1 2\rangle|\frac 1 2, -\frac 1 2\rangle = 
\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\Big(|0,0\rangle + |1,0\rangle\Big) $$